# How to convert factor to numeric?

Tags: r

I'm analyzing data to University, and i dont know how to convert factor like: `58.4 [57.4-60.3]`to numeric

I did :

```
data$male <- as.character(data$male)
data$male <- as.numeric(data$male)
```

but it doesnt work.

Warning message:
`NAs introduced by coercion`

Could you help me with this problem ?

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output.  Based on the string, what values you want to extract.  It could be that you want to extract the first numeric values `as.numeric(sub("\\s+.*", "", data$male))`

Comment: Yes, i want to extract the first element of this phrase. Thank you very much. Sorry for syntax, its my first post on forum like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can match one or more whitespace (`\\s+`) followed by other characters to the end and replace it with `""` in `sub` and then convert to `numeric`

```
data$male <- as.numeric(sub("\\s+.*", "", data$male))
```